# Python sklearn r2_score confusion for linear regressions

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Sorry if this is a trivial question.
Using the sklearn library, one can calculate the coefficient of determination, r squared, for the following lists:

```py
y_true = [200,280,320,346.47]

y_pred = [228.6,307.8,414.4,376.5]

print(r_score(y_true,y_pred))
```

[OUTPUT: 0.07]

A different definition for R squared is made by Microsoft Excel, when using the linear regression tool: the returned value for R² is about 0.86

Is there any resource in sklearn or somewhere else that lets me use Excel's definition for R²? Thanks in advance.

Comment: IF you're asking for official documentation, here it is https://scikit-learn.org/0.21/documentation.html

Comment: I think this helps as well https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-regression-in-python-sklearn-vs-excel-6790187dc9ca

Answer (score 0):

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) R2 is the proportion of the variance in the dependent variable that is predictable from the independent variable(s).

If your `y_pred` are indeed the predicted values, then we can calculate according to this formula:

[image]

```
import numpy as np

ss_total = np.var(np.array(y_true))*len(y_true)
ss_res = ((np.array(y_pred) - np.array(y_true))**2).sum()
print(1 - ss_res/ss_total)

0.06853942803971502
```

Which is exactly what is returned by sklearn:

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
print(r2_score(y_true,y_pred))
0.06853942803971502
```

When you put it into excel, you are **regressing** your prediction against your true values, and then the r2 provided is of course very high, but wrong.

Below I calculate the coefficient correlation between your predicted and true, take the square which gives us r^2 and I get the same value as you:

```
from scipy import stats
slope, intercept, r, p, se = stats.linregress(y_pred, y_true)
r2 = r**2
print(r2)

0.8602435256742592
```